# MySQL only selecting records with ID X,Y,Z and 3 hasMany relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables:

```
t1.id
t1.name

t2.id
t2.t1_id
t2.t3_id
t2.t4_id

t3.id
t3.name

t4.id
t4.name
```

t1 hasMany t2 and t2 hasOne t3 and t2 hasOne t4.

Now, i have a set of three Id's (1,2,3). I want to return the t1.id of the t1 that has Id's t3_id (1,2,3) and t4_id 1. And the amount of links in t2 HAS to be the exact amount of the t3_id's (3 in this case).

I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t2.t4_id
WHERE t3.id IN (1,2,3) AND t4.id = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING count(t2.t3_id) = 3
```

But this also returns t1.id's of instances that have e.g. t2_id (1,2,3,4).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use real table/variables names so it is clearer to understand what joins are being made and why? Also some sample data from each table would be helpful.

Comment: it doesn't seen that t2 can't be (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Am I correct in saying the reason that row is invalid is because it has a t4_id = 4? Despite the fact that there may be exactly three other rows with t4_id = 1?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following possible rows in t2:

```
| t1_id | t2_id | t3_id | t4_id |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |   1   |   1   |
|   1   |   2   |   2   |   1   |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   1   |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |
```

In your query, you're going to pull rows that have exactly three `t3_id`s that have a `t4_id` of 1, which will work here. That last row will not be returned. However, it doesn't change the fact that `t1_id = 1` meets your criteria, so as it is written that instance of `t1_id` will be returned.

If you want rows that only exist in t2 three times, *all* with t4_id = 1, you'll need to add a check to make sure there are no rows with an invalid t4_id.

Comment: Basically you're saying that it can't be done this way and it needs some added logic (a subquery or postprocessing in pseudocode such as PHP)?

Comment: @MarcelEmblazoned I'm going to do some quick testing, but this can be done. Can you try to make an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data that shows the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score -1):

**Please disregard this answer.**

In absence of actual data in tables, I could come up with the
 following - just adding a count(*).

```
SELECT t1.id, count(*)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
INNER JOIN t4 ON t4.id = t2.t4_id
WHERE t3.id IN (1,2,3) AND t4.id = 1
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING count(t2.t3_id) = 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here by adding an extra column to the select statement.

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly the same as my query, the count(*) just add a count of the t3.id's